# Read serial data from multiple arduino

Tags: python, serial, arduino, rfid

Please help me find problem in this code:

```
import serial
ser=serial.Serial("/dev/ttyACM0",9600)
ser.baudrate=9600
ser1=serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0",9600)
ser1.baudrate=9600
ser2=serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB1",9600)
ser2.baudrate=9600

while True: 

 read_ser=ser.readline()
 read_ser1=ser1.readline()
 read_ser1=ser2.readline()
 print(read_ser)
 print(read_ser1)
 print(read_ser2)
```

I expect that it will show me message from connected Arduino. Arduino send it when I apply card to RFID reader. But, it send only from first `ser`

**Update:**

I connect 3 Arduino Uno to Raspberry Pi 3 via USB.
Each Arduino connect with RFID-RC522.

```
ls -l /dev/ttyACM*  
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 166, 0 Oct 18 19:17 /dev/ttyACM0
```

But Arduinos connect to `/dev/ttyUSB0` `/dev/ttyUSB1` `/dev/ttyACM0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works as I expected

```
import serial
ser=serial.Serial("/dev/ttyACM0",9600,timeout=1)
ser.baudrate=9600
ser1=serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0",9600,timeout=1)
ser1.baudrate=9600
ser2=serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB1",9600,timeout=1)
ser2.baudrate=9600
while True: # Run forever

 read_ser=ser.readline()
 if (read_ser != ""):
        print(read_ser)
 read_ser1=ser1.readline()
 if (read_ser1 != ""):
         print(read_ser1)
 read_ser2=ser2.readline()
 if (read_ser2 != ""):
         print(read_ser2)
```

Thank you @jasonharper